# How to straighten out multiple selected edges to one axis?

Tags: edges

I was just wondering if there was a way to get all selected edges completely straight. For example how to get something like this [image]

so that the edges circled in red are all completely straight along the X axis, like all the edges turn into one straight line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the last vertex but anyway.

Just select all the vertices and then hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale then tap the direction you want to scale. In my case Y. Then tap  <kbd>0</kbd> on the number pad.

[image]

Comment: glad it helped, please accept the answer if you dont mind.

Comment: i got you once it lets me